# Python Function - Drawing a Triangle with a python fucntion

Tags: python-3.x

I've create the following program to draw two triangles in Python 3, one half the size of the other with the robot driving away with pen down.

This is all good and have the solution in place

[Working solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NiuN.png)

However I'm obsessed in making my code shorter using a python function.

[Guidance notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63UMG.png)

I have added an optional variable in like the content advises:
[additional variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObR1n.png)

This so I can draw add an argument against the function whenever I call the function to make different sizes of the triangle easily.

Can you see where I'm going wrong here?

Call the function but add an argument against another variable (SIDE_LENGTH) to make smaller or larger versions of the shape

Comment: Please include the code as text, not as a picture?

Answer (score 0):

You have called the `draw_triangle` function with an argument, but in the function definition it is not expecting an argument.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp) you can learn more about how to use function arguments.

Comment: Apologies New to this site and the world of programming as you can probably tell.....

Comment: No worries, but you posted your code in a comment. I recommend editing your post in putting it between tilde signs (like ` code `) so it will be readable :)

Comment: Understood :-), the code I've written as delivered the solution however I'm just trying to incorporate it into a function. Allowing me to obviously call it more efficiently but against a parameter SIDE_LENGTH to allow me to draw different sized triangles. Hope you can help me...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it after understanding the link between the additional 'side' parameter and how it can be passed into an argument:

````
SIDES = 4

# Try to draw a square
STEERING = -100
TURN_ROTATIONS = 1.6
TURN_SPEED = 10

STRAIGHT_SPEED_PC = SpeedPercent(40)
STRAIGHT_ROTATIONS = 8

def draw_square(side=STRAIGHT_ROTATIONS):
    """Draw square of specified side length."""
    for side_number in range(SIDES):
        # Go straight
        # Set the left and right motors in a forward direction
        # and run for the number of rotations specified by: side
        tank_drive.on_for_rotations(STRAIGHT_SPEED_PC,
                                    STRAIGHT_SPEED_PC,
                                    # Use provided side length
                                    side)

        #Turn
        # Set the robot to turn on the spot
        # and run for a certain number of rotations *of the wheels*
        tank_turn.on_for_rotations(STEERING,
                                   SpeedPercent(TURN_SPEED),
                                   TURN_ROTATIONS)
        
        
# Call the function to draw a small size square
draw_square(4)

# And an even smaller square
draw_square(2)```
````